# kivy - how to prepare app for touch events

Tags: python, android, ios, kivy

I am developing an app using Kivy for Android and IOS, i haven't tried it on any mobile yet but i have been noticing that i need to add some sort off 'touch' events so the buttons, swipes and etc will work on a mobile touchscreen.
i've tried searching around for examples but i didn't exactly get the concept, and i was wondering what exactly do i need to do for it to be ready for touch events, i am thinking of making a 'swiping touch' to move between pages on both sides, what do i need to do to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to swipe through pages as you have mentioned. It could be a nice option to use PageLayout. Check the docs:https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.pagelayout.html
PageLayout is where you have several pages and you can swipe through them. It could be suitable for you.
Here is a very simple example.Where you will have three pages

```
PageLayout:
    Button:
        text: 'page1'
    Button:
        text: 'page2'
    Button:
        text: 'page3'
```

Here is a advanced pagelayout example from kv file. The pagelyout then consists of floatlayouts. But you could use other layouts too

```
<Example>:
    PageLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            id: string1
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb:utils.get_color_from_hex("#2BFFFA")
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos:self.pos


            Image:
                size_hint:.9,1
                pos_hint:{"top": 1,"right": 1}
                source: "string/str1.png"
        FloatLayout:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb:utils.get_color_from_hex("#39FF22")
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos:self.pos
            Image:
                size_hint:.9,1
                pos_hint:{"top": 1,"right": 1}
                source: "string/str1_sol.png"
        FloatLayout:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb:utils.get_color_from_hex("#2BFFFA")
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos:self.pos
            Image:
                size_hint:.9,1
                pos_hint:{"top": 1,"right": 1}
                source: "string/str2.png"
```

Notice that my main layout is a pagelayout and in the floatlayout I have floatlayouts. So now I have three pages to swipe through

Or you could use a screemanger to manage your screens. . And then you just have to click on a button and then you will automatically switch screens. Here is a example. This is better than pagelayouts.

```
import kivy


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class ScreenOne(Screen):

    def __init__ (self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenOne, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        my_box1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        my_label1 = Label(text="BlaBlaBla on screen 1", font_size='24dp')
        my_button1 = Button(text="Go to screen 2",size_hint_y=None, size_y=100)
        my_button1.bind(on_press=self.changer)
        my_box1.add_widget(my_label1)
        my_box1.add_widget(my_button1)
        self.add_widget(my_box1)

    def changer(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'screen2'

class ScreenTwo(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super (ScreenTwo,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        my_box1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        my_label1 = Label(text="BlaBlaBla on screen 2",font_size='24dp')
        my_button1 = Button(text="Go to screen 1",size_hint_y=None, size_y=100)
        my_button1.bind(on_press=self.changer)
        my_box1.add_widget(my_label1)
        my_box1.add_widget(my_button1)
        self.add_widget(my_box1)

    def changer(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'screen1'

class TestApp(App):

        def build(self):
            my_screenmanager = ScreenManager()
            screen1 = ScreenOne(name='screen1')
            screen2 = ScreenTwo(name='screen2')
            my_screenmanager.add_widget(screen1)
            my_screenmanager.add_widget(screen2)
            return my_screenmanager

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```